# Detect if face is in fixed area of video frame

Tags: javascript, face-detection, face-api

I am working on a project where I need to take picture of the frame automatically from live video when the face of person who is in that video is in a fixed area of that video. I am using faceapi for face detection. I tried to use mouth, nose and eyes coordinate but it's not working because those coordinates are changing and I am founding same coordinate in different place and all persons face shape are not same. Here is my js code-

```
const video = document.getElementById('video')

Promise.all([
  faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
]).then(startVideo)

function startVideo() {
  navigator.getUserMedia(
    { video: {} },
    stream => video.srcObject = stream,
    err => console.error(err)
  )
}

video.addEventListener('play', () => {
  const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video)
  document.body.append(canvas)
  const displaySize = { width: video.width, height: video.height }
  faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize)
  setInterval(async () => {
    const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions()
    const count = await faceapi
      .detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions())
      .withFaceLandmarks()
    if(count.length>1){
      alert("There are multiple faces in the frame. Please keep only one face");
    }  
    else{
      const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize)
      canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
      faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections)
      faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections)
      faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections)
      const landmarks = await faceapi.detectFaceLandmarks(video)
      const mouth = landmarks.getMouth()
      const nose = landmarks.getNose()
      const leftEye = landmarks.getLeftEye();
      console.log(mouth[0]._x, mouth[0]._y);
      console.log(nose[0]._x, nose[0]._y)    
      console.log(leftEye[0]._x, leftEye[0]._y)
      if((((mouth[0]._x<=330) && (mouth[0]._x>=280)) && ((mouth[0]._y<=310) && (mouth[0]._y>=260))) &&
      (((nose[0]._x<=320) && (nose[0]._x>=270)) && ((nose[0]._y<=220) && (nose[0]._y>=160))) &&
      (((leftEye[0]._x<=270) && (leftEye[0]._x>=210)) && ((leftEye[0]._y<=240) && (leftEye[0]._y>=180))))
      {
          alert("Click for perfect photo");        
      }
      else{
        //alert("Image not ready");
      }
    }    
  }, 100)
})
```

And this is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script defer src="face-api.min.js"></script>
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    canvas {
      position: absolute;
    }

    #box {
      width: 450px;
      height: 325px;
      position: absolute;
      background-image: url("paper.png");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 450px 325px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="box"></div>
  <video id="video" width="500" height="375" autoplay muted></video></body>
  <br/>
</body>
</html>
```

I put the image on the video frame because I want to click image automatically when face is in that area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use detection box height, width and co-ordinates to calculate the face position and ratio of the face in the frame.

```
const frame_height = resizedDetections[0].detection._box._height
const frame_width = resizedDetections[0].detection._box._width
const frame_x = resizedDetections[0].detection._box._x
const frame_y = resizedDetections[0].detection._box._y
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also add an additional frame using absolute css position to render the optimum frame for the user to put their head in. I would recommend;
-using the face landmarks array iterating through them within the bounding box of an optimum dimension for a maximum face size
-using the face bounding box for a minimum size of the face.
Hence capturing an optimum face size =]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import * as faceapi from "face-api.js";
import Loading from "./Loading";
import { mapAcne, mapPigmentation, mapPores, mapWrinkles } from "../common";


const WebcamComponent = () => {
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
  const [expressions, setExpressions] = useState([]);
  const [age, setAge] = useState(null);
  const [gender, setGender] = useState(null);
  const [skinFeatures, setSkinFeatures] = useState({
    skinColor: "",
    wrinkles: "",
    acne: "",
    pores: "",
    pigmentation: "",
  });

  const videoRef = useRef();
  const videoCanvasRef = useRef();
  const videoHeight = 400;
  const videoWidth = 400;

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadModels = async () => {
      const MODEL_URL = "/models"; // Update to the correct path
      setInitializing(true);
      await faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL);
      await faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL);
      await faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL);
      await faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL);
      await faceapi.nets.ageGenderNet.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL);
      startWebcam();
    };

    loadModels();

    return () => {
      if (videoRef.current.srcObject) {
        videoRef.current.srcObject.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
      }
    };
  }, []);

  const startWebcam = async () => {
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true,
      });
      videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
      videoRef.current.onloadedmetadata = () => {
        setInitializing(false);
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("getUserMedia Error: ", error);
    }
  };

  const handleVideoPlay = () => {
    setInterval(async () => {
      if (initializing) {
        setInitializing(false);
      }
      const displaySize = { width: videoWidth, height: videoHeight };
      faceapi.matchDimensions(videoCanvasRef.current, displaySize);
      const detections = await faceapi
        .detectAllFaces(videoRef.current, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions())
        .withFaceLandmarks()
        .withFaceExpressions()
        .withAgeAndGender()
        .withFaceDescriptors();

      const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize);

      // Clear previous dots
      const ctx = videoCanvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, videoWidth, videoHeight);

      faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(videoCanvasRef.current, resizedDetections);

      // Extract and set detected expressions and additional features
      if (resizedDetections.length > 0) {
        const expressionsObj = resizedDetections[0].expressions;
        const detectedExpressions = Object.keys(expressionsObj).filter(
          (expression) => expressionsObj[expression] > 0.7
        );
        const faceDescriptor = resizedDetections[0].descriptor;

        const [
          // skinColorValue,
          wrinklesValue,
          poresValue,
          acneValue,
          pigmentationValue,
        ] = faceDescriptor;

        // Map numerical values to text descriptions for skin features
        const mappedFeatures = {
          wrinkles: mapWrinkles(Math.abs(wrinklesValue).toFixed(1)),
          acne: mapAcne(Math.abs(acneValue).toFixed(1)),
          pores: mapPores(Math.abs(poresValue).toFixed(1)),
          pigmentation: mapPigmentation(Math.abs(pigmentationValue).toFixed(1)),
        };

        // Update state with mapped features
        setSkinFeatures(mappedFeatures);

        // Extract and set age and gender
        setAge(resizedDetections[0].age);
        setGender(resizedDetections[0].gender);
        if (detectedExpressions.length > 0) {
          setExpressions(detectedExpressions);
        }
      }
    }, 1000);
  };

 return (
    <div className="h-screen w-screen flex flex-row justify-between items-center border-2 border-white overflow-hidden">
      {initializing && <Loading />}

      <div className="h-full w-5/12 flex justify-center items-center relative">
        <video
          ref={videoRef}
          className="h-full w-full object-fill"
          autoPlay
          playsInline
          onPlay={handleVideoPlay}
          muted
        />
        <canvas
          ref={videoCanvasRef}
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          className="absolute w-full h-full"
        ></canvas>
      </div>

      
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Try not to just paste a huge block of code, it would be better to provide a smaller block of code and explain what it does and how it solves the asker's problem.